# How to select build architecture with SCons

Tags: scons

I started with SCons yesterday but I encountered a problem while trying to convert my project from Premake to SCons. I didn't find how to change build architecture. If I don't set anything, SCons will compile the project for x86 architecture but I would like to have an option to compile my project to x64 and to ARM architectures. Also I want my project to be cross-platform/cross-compiler so I would like to avoid any compiler specific flags like gcc's `-m64`. Is there anyway of doing so?

Comment: You'll have to build a bunch of logic to support cross compiling. It's not baked in. if you google "cross compiling with SCons" my guess is you'll find some useful information.

Comment: @bdbaddog thanks for your reply! So there is no cross-compiler solution for this? I know that SCons isn't fully built for cross-compiler projects but some things can be set once for every compiler like defines: `env.Append(CPPDEFINES=["DEFINE", "MORE_DEFINES"])`. It seems that I will have to use compiler-specific flags for now.

Comment: Lot's of similar questions on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898584/how-can-i-use-a-cross-compiler-with-scons  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848516/unable-to-cross-compile-for-arm-with-scons-because-fo-is-added https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/PlatformToolConfig#markdown-header-cross-compilation